# when i am trying to install radium package to Reactjs this Error occur what should i do for this?

Tags: npm

I am a new developer and these error torture me.

```
npm install --save radium
+ radium@0.26.0
updated 1 package and audited 1374 packages in 11.052s

23 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details       

found 34 vulnerabilities (31 low, 1 moderate, 2 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Run command: `npm audit fix` this will solve. Anyway it's not an error just a warning as per the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

This is an npm feature called `audit` so that you can check whether your installed modules have known vulnerabilities and  exploits. Developers or other users of these modules can announce possible exploits and probabily release a patch if they found anything unsafe in the module. Then everytime you install modules or run audit manually you will see these warnings. You can run `npm audit fix` to let npm fix them if possible. However some modules does not have a patch or cannot be fixed automatically so you have to fix them by hand. Anyway if you are just developing locally you can ignore them.